# Почему youtube_video_uploader_bot не запускается?

Tags: python, youtube

У меня есть код, который работает с помощью библиотеки youtube_video_uploader_bot:

```py
from youtube_video_uploader_bot import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    youtube.login(username="username",password="password")
    youtube.upload(title='Testing Upload ', video_path="/Users/aleksejhodarev/Downloads/t.mp4", kid_type='Yes, it\'s made for kids', description='I am just testing', type='Public')
```

Однако он выдает текст:

```
It currently works on windows only
```

Он переводится как "Сейчас это работает только в окнах"

Может он имеет ввиду, что он может работать только на Windows или дело в чём-то другом?

Comment: Да, только под Windows. Этот же текст написан и на [его страничке](https://pypi.org/project/youtube-video-uploader-bot/) в описании.

Comment: А что, есть какая-то разница?

Comment: Видимо существенная. Например, отсутствие каких-либо специфических библиотек, которое есть только в Виндах.